# Magento Rest API - multiple product list in one call

Tags: api, rest, magento, magento2

I want to access specified multiple product list in one call. for example access all the products in  category id 14 and 15.

This provide the product list id 14:

```
/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=14
```

This provide the product list id 15:

```
/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=15
```

But if I want to get both in one call: is possible to make somenthing like this ?:

```
/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=14,15
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the in condition type

```
GET <host>/rest/<store_code>/V1/products?
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=entity_id&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=1,2,3,4,5&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=in
```

This example can be extended to work with category etc as you require, see examples

```
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/rest/performing-searches.html
```